# Returning values at a specific DateTime Index - based on conditional testing

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, datetime

I have the below DataFrame:

```
           Var1   Var2  Var3   Var4
2019-01-01  0.5   0.0    0.1   0.05
2019-01-02  0.5   0.0    0.2   0.09
2019-01-03  0.0   0.5    0.4   0.02
```

And the below function which iterates through the df:

```
def switch(row):
    if row.Var1 >= 0.5 and row.Var2 <= 0.5:
        return 'foo'
    elif row.Va1 <=0.5 and row.Var2 >= 0.5:
        return 'bar'
    else:
        return 'baz'
```

I've applied the function to the empty pd.Series `port_switching` to return the following output:

```
port_switching = pd.Series([])
port_switching = df.apply(switch, axis=1)

print(port_switching)

2019-01-01    foo
2019-01-02    foo
2019-01-03    bar
Freq: D, dtype: object
```

I was assisted by @jadore801120 who created the function, but now my final problem is this: Where this function returns 'foo' or 'bar' or 'baz', I need to figure out how to return the value of Var3 or Var4 depending on which condition was passed, i.e. the, 'if', 'elif' or 'else'.

- So in the above example, at 2019-01-01 'foo' would be returned as Var3's value at 2019-01-01 i.e. 0.1.
- Likewise, because the 'if' condition was passed at 2019-01-02 then Var3's 2019-01-02 value would be returned i.e. 0.2.
- Finally, at 2019-01-03 the 'elif' condition was passed, so the function should return Var4's value at 2019-01-04 i.e. 0.02.

The final product should look something like this:

```
print(port_switching)
2019-01-01    0.1
2019-01-02    0.2
2019-01-03    0.02
Freq: D, dtype: object
```

Assume, I'm working with a large data set and cannot input these values manually. I will continue to go it alone, but if anyone can offer a solution - it would put several days of work to rest!

Comment: there is no Low or High column in your data

Comment: @sammywemmy - these are simply the names of Var1 and Var 2 in this example, I have edited the post to reflect the example names of Var1 and Var2

Comment: you have three conditions. if the first condition succeeds, then var3, if the last condition succeeds, var4, what about the middle condition?

Comment: The last condition is necessary for when I apply this function to a larger data set with greater variation in data. - it will say something like "check value" or etc.

Comment: so the last column will be a string? in a column of integers? could you explain better? that way, we can make room for it in the code

Comment: The last column i.e. the one you provided in your solution, would be integers - so this works perfectly. The previous function was provided by another user who was offering the "skeleton" of an idea to a possible function, thus included the "if, elif, and else'. Because In reality, I'll only be using two sets of data (as provided in your solution below) I don't suppose I'll need a third "else" output. Does this make sense?

Comment: sure. makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[numpy select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) should help with your challenge, plus it is vectorized, so should be much faster than using `apply` :

```
cond1 = df.Var1.ge(0.5) & (df.Var2.le(0.5))
cond2 = df.Var1.le(0.5) & (df.Var2.ge(0.5))
condlist = [cond1, cond2]
choicelist = [df.Var3, df.Var4]
df['result'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)


           Var1 Var2    Var3    Var4    result
2019-01-01  0.5 0.0    0.1      0.05    0.10
2019-01-02  0.5 0.0    0.2      0.09    0.20
2019-01-03  0.0 0.5    0.4      0.02    0.02
```